# having trouble saving numbers

Tags: python, numbers, saving-data

pretty new to learning python and wanted to give myself a challenge, but have ran into an issue where i cannot get my numbers to change. If I subtract a number from it then subtract another number from it again on a different line of code it does not update from the original number. what i need is something that will do this:
a = 100
b- 20
a- b =80
a - b =60
hopefully this makes some sense :)

```
def viper_battle():

print("viper has the first attack,")

while player_health >= 1 or viper_health >= 1:
    viper_atk = random.choice(viper_turn_list)
    if viper_atk == 1:
        print("viper has attacked you leaving you at", player_health - viper_dmg, "health")
    elif viper_atk == 2:
        print("viper is performing ship repairs only dealing half damage to you")
    elif viper_atk == 3:
        print("oh no viper used  a special allowing them to deal the same damage as the health they have leaving us at", player_health - viper_special)
    if player_health <= 0:
        print("you lost!")
        sys.exit()

    attack_1 = input("what is your move: ")
    if attack_1 == "a" or attack_1 == "A":
        print("Direct hit!", viper_health - player_base_dmg, "health remains of our enemy")
    elif attack_1 == "s" or attack_1 == "S":
        print("The swarm was set upon Viper dealing massive damage", viper_health - player_special,"health remains of our enemy")
    elif attack_1 == "r" or attack_1 == "R":
        print("repairs were made tou our ship", player_health + player_repair)
    elif attack_1 == "d" or attack_1 == "D":
        print("we could not handle the heat, we retreated successfully")
        sys.exit
    if viper_health <= 0:
        print("we won this battle!")
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: last bit messed up a bit was meant to say a = 100, b = 20, a-b =80, a-b=60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a = 100, b = 20, a-b =80` when you say a-b = 80 that is just a calculation (we would call that an expression). It doesn't change the value of `a` or `b` or anything else. You meed to assign your result to something you can use.

```
a = 100
b = 20
a = a - b # 80
a = a - b # 60
```